# Passing a reference of an object to activity

Tags: android

I have a reference to an anonymous class object that I want to pass to an activity. It is a kind of reference to a callback fn which gets called based on an action on activity i.e. click of button. But, I dont know a way to do so as activities can not be instantiated directly (done only through startActivity) and using intents will pass my object by value not by reference. So, I need tips on a good solution. I want to avoid statics.

Comment: use parcelable.

Comment: I don't think pass by reference is possible in Java/Android.. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/3111083. In your case you can use Parceble or Serilizable..

Comment: Well, yes according to Java language, Java passes references ( they decided to call pointers references) by values. In C++ paradigm, it passes by references.

Comment: @takesavy Can you give any source which say's pass by reference is possible in Java..( they decided to call pointers references thus confusing newbies .Because those references are passed by value.)

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No You cannot pass objects as references to activities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CustomListing currentListing = new CustomListing();
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable(Constants.CUSTOM_LISTING, currentListing);
i.putExtras(b);
i.setClass(this, SearchDetailsActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Afterwards to call

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null)
 mCurrentListing = b.getParcelable(Constants.CUSTOM_LISTING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

Create a public static method in the Activity to which you want to pass the reference of an object.

```
public static void openActivity(Activity activity, Class object){
        YourNextActivity.object = object;
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, YourNextActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Call this method from current Activity :

```
YourNextActivity.openActivity(this, classObject);
```

Comment: this.object = object in a static method ?

Comment: Edited it. Check now.

Comment: I want to avoid statics - " YourNextActivity.object = object;"